# True/False to Yes/No in Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Am using Jquery DataTable to display the searched results and results are displayed as i receive in the json.

Am trying to change the result at field level.

For example :

If any of the fields received in JSON is True i need to display as Yes and False should be displayed as No irespective of column names.

Is there a way i can achieve this using any DataTable events.

If yes...sample code would be great

*There are other options available in sQL anc C#. just want to know if i can do this with DataTable

Thanks

Comment: you can achieve this.

Comment: @VondRitz some samples would be great :)

Comment: @VondRitz i edited my question tooo :)

Comment: http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns. Read about aoColumns fnRender  or  much better the newest is aoColumns mRender / mData to manipulate data each row of datatable on its creation.

Comment: @VondRitz Am loading column dynamically so this wont help

Comment: Can you make the change server-side prior to creating the json object?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this [Datatable Usage](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns)

if you will use newest version of datatable I suggest used `mRender` or `mData`. if the older version use `fnRender`.

```js
// Create a comma separated list from an array of objects
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "sources/deep.txt",
    "aoColumns": [{
        "mData": "engine"
      },{
        "mData": "browser"
      },{
        "mData": "platform",
        "mRender": "[, ].name"
      }]
  });
});

// Use as a function to create a link from the data source
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      "aTargets": [0],
      "mData": "download_link",
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        return '<a href="' + data + '">Download</a>';
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Column wise data rendering use below code

```js
"title": "Active", 
"data": "IsActive", 
"searchable": false,
"render": function(IsActive, type, full, meta) {
  if (IsActive) {
    return 'Yes';
  } else {
    return 'No';
  }
}
```